# How to store rich-text in database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rich-text-editor, draftjs

I want to store data that is being edited with Draft.js and React (in the UI) into a MySQL database.

I am not sure in which format should I store my data, so that I can fetch the data from database and display it on the page with the formatting applied while writing the text?

For example - I applied bold style to some of the text and gave some line breaks. How to store this info for later use?

Please suggest a format to store my data.

Comment: Sounds like you are reinventing GoogleDocs.

Answer (score 6):

You could save it as a string format. To elaborate, you can use a JSON-serialized string of the `ContentState` as mentioned in the [Draft JS docs](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-data-conversion).

Draft JS has utility methods `convertFromRaw` and `convertToRaw` to help you. Check out the docs linked above, they are pretty clear.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still facing this issue, basically you have to convertToRaw, then JSON.stringify it. Then this can be sent to your backend as a string. To display it, make a GET request for that particular data, then JSON.parse it and then convertFromRaw. Pass this into another RichTextEditor as the editorState but set the readOnly={true}

Answer (score 1):

Draft.js is archiving.

A new alternative is [lexical](https://lexical.dev/)

You can find its playground here: https://playground.lexical.dev/